# Credit Disputes Refund & Credit Fraud Refund

Tags: credit-card, bank-account, fraud, refund

I had over $200 stolen from my account and I reported it to a bank management.

After a week I got that $200 money back to my account which shows as Credit Disputes Refund.

Then I got over $1500 to my account as Credit Fraud Refund.
Does anyone knows what the hell happened?
Why did I got that extra $1500?
Should I contact my bank or keep in silence? :)

It's been 4 days since they transferred it. Any information would be appreciated!

EDITED: These Credit Fraud Refunds were made as separate 3 refunds.

EDITED 2: As I can't add comments I will answer some questions here: I will not name the bank but I called them yesterday and they should call me today to give me feedback on what happened. I think these 3 transactions were supposed to be to in different accounts and because they refunded my missing money very quickly I am happy with that. I could have waited couple of months and see if they were looking for that money or not, I could have invested them into stocks quickly etc, but that is never a case. Thanks for the feedback on that

Comment: To quote a line from the TV show Friends, "What bank is this?"

Comment: `Should I keep money that doesn't belong to me?`  No.  Kids these days.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should contact the bank and report it.  They will eventually "find" that money if it's not yours.  You better get it over with rather than having more surprises later.

Comment: Unfortunately Brick is right. They can even freeze your account if you end up spending it and they find out which they will...eventually.